# How to Capture and manage requirements from a statement of work (SOW)

Tags: analysis, requirements, capture

Can anyone gives us tricks, uses case, book and any other ressources for how to Capture and manage requirements from a statement of work(SOW).

Comment: Side note: Commit to the beta for the Software Engineering SE site and it'll be a great home for questions like this: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6922/software-engineering

Comment: I would suggest trying to capture as many business action statements as you can. Usually business actions turn into either modules or functions. Not much of a tip, but it's the first one I use to show people...

Answer (score 1):

A Statement of Work usually identifies your business objectives and spells out the scope. From there I would (very loosely):

1. Attempt a very high-level model of business functionality (my preferred form is a Use Case Model).
2. Engage with the business owner(s) to confirm the high-level model.
3. Attempt - in conjunction with the business owner(s), to model the business requirements (my preferred method is use cases).

It's possible to capture requirements as a list in a document or wiki. It's also possible to capture them purely diagrammatically. I use Visio. I've also used requirements management tools such as RequisitePro. I prefer use cases that start out as diagrams and add step-wise narratives as needed.